# Is there any delegate method for network operation in CoreData mapping with RestKit 0.20

Tags: objective-c, restkit-0.20

I want to delete existing managed objects from CoreData if network operation is success in CoreData mapping with RestKit. We have a completion block in CoreData mapping with RestKit but we will reach there only after saving the objects in context.

Comment: You want to delete all items from the data store that aren't in the response you just received from the server ?

Answer (score 0):

RestKit can perform a delete for you as part of the mapping process, you just need to provide the fetch request to tell it how to find the items that you want to be deleted. Check the documentation [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html), in the section "Fetch Request Blocks and Deleting Orphaned Objects".

Using this technique does require that you're using `RKObjectManager`. If you aren't you can still run a fetch request and do the purge yourself but you'll need to deal with not deleting the new items yourself.